# What is a MySQL Server Instance?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand what is meant by a Server Instance in MySQL. Googling for the term "MySQL Server Instance" reveals nothing, and the only reference I can find in the documentation refers to using the New Server Instance Wizard, but doesn't seem to explain why I'd ever want to use this.

Coming from a Microsoft SQL Server background, a (named) instance is a completely separate and isolated installation of the server, running in its own process and on its own port.  However, in MySQL a (server) instance seems to be a different beast, as for starters it seems to use the same port as my "existing" "instance".

From the Home page of MySQL Workbench, I have the option on the right hand side to create a New Server Instance.  What is a MySQL Server Instance, and why would I ever want to create a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A server instance is a MySQL server running somewhere, and also how to connect to it.  See the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-server-administration-new-server-instance.html), which says:

> A server instance is created to provide a way of connecting to a server to be managed.

Though it is somewhat circular, it makes sense from configuring the control manager's connection options where one can choose to connect to any number of MySQL servers, or connect to the same server in several different ways (like through a VPN or secondary network).

Comment: So on MySQL there is no way of creating separate, isolated "instances" like you can on Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @Mikey Cee:  I never said any such thing.  I was just answering your question.  There could be several MySQLs running on a single server, or there could be one MySQL server running on a distributed parallel server.  MySQL is much more flexible than MS SQL Server.

Comment: @wallyk From your description you linked it implies that the term "instance" in the context of the workbench refers to a connection/configuration pair, where you could have multiple of these for a single server.  When you say "could be several MySQLs running", this seems like something different than simply multiple connection configurations to a single server.

Answer (score 1):

From this it appears each instance actually does have its own port judging from this guide to setting up an additional instance:
http://www.ducea.com/2009/01/19/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-the-same-machine/

I'm not sure how this interacts in terms of named pipes on Windows though.